# Restart Computer After IE Reset

Tags: command-line, browser, internet-explorer, reboot

I am using IE11 (latest KB) and I tested on Win 10, Win 8.1, and Win 7.

I reset IE using the menu options: Tools → Advanced → Reset

After reset is complete, IE showed a yellow bar at the bottom with the following message:

[image: You need to restart you computer for the changes to take effect.]

I can also reset IE settings via this command (same as above):

`RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl ResetIEtoDefaults`

IE does not prompt the same message as above. I ran the command with IE open and closed, but no prompt to restart the computer.

So, now I am wondering if both methods perform the same reset, why restart message is not prompted in the second one.

Second, (*lot of us may not know this*), what settings are effected with the restart?